# Meteortesting mocha Code Coverage Error: Failed to save json / html report

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, istanbul

Meteor Coverage does not create coverage report:

```
Error: Failed to save html report // same with json
at packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.handleCoverage.js:37:18
at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1286:24)
```

i do my call with:

`COVERAGE_OUT_JSON=1 COVERAGE_VERBOSE=1 COVERAGE=1 COVERAGE_APP_FOLDER=$PWD meteor test --once --full-app  --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --extra-packages lmieulet:meteor-coverage`

meteor version 1.11.1
nodejs version 12.18
lmieulet:meteor-coverage@3.2.0

Comment: have you verified that the folder it is supposed to write to is writable by the user running the test?

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes and there are also some css and js files, but the report file is missing / exists with 0 bytes

Comment: hm, then I don't know. Could you provide a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: I don't think i can, since that would take to much time if even reproducable on a small separate app. I could provide you with my package and version files if you want?